# Spinnaker LDAP using Halyard

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am having an issue in setting up my spinnaker ldap authentication to windows active directory

gate-local.yml -->
ldap:
   managerDn: cn=svc_spinnaker_auth,ou=SERVICE ACCOUNTS,ou=DOMAIN ESTATE,dc=testdomain,dc=com
   managerPassword: XXXX
   groupSearchBase: cn=ADM_Spinnaker_Auth_Global,ou=SECURITY,ou=GROUPS,ou=ELEVATED ACCESS,ou=DOMAIN ESTATE,dc=testdomain,dc=com

halyard command -->
hal config security authn ldap edit --url=ldap://10.34.XXX.XX:XXX/DC=domain,DC=com --user-search-base="CN=ADM_Spinnaker_Auth_Global,OU=SECURITY,OU=GROUPS,OU=ELEVATED ACCESS,OU=DOMAIN ESTATE,DC=domain,DC=com" --user-search-filter="(sAMAccOUntName={0})"

Answer (score 0):

I've setup my user search filter to be below:

`(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={0})(instanceType=4))`

I had tried what you did before but it didn't work exactly that way. Above worked better. I also had to put my entire config in a `gate-local.yml` file. Adding it through hal config was not copying my `managerDN` and `managerPassword` to my `spinnaker` deployment even though it was in my config file.